# How do you type fractional lengths into blender?

Tags: modeling

No, not 1/{number}, {number}/{other number}. Every time I try and type a fractional transformation into blender, it forces me to only type 1/{something} when the reality is most people want as much precise control over the numerator too. How can I make blender do what it is supposed to do and just type any fraction?

Comment: I can't reproduce this, at first sight... could you just add the details, Blender version, an example of a field that isn't working?

Comment: Blender is forgiving enough to allow you to enter minor equations such as "2m + 1/4m" "5/10cm", or most things that are well formatted.  I'm having trouble understanding your issue.

Comment: I'm having trouble understand your statement since you have failed to provide proof what you say is true.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you are talking about the numerical input of *Modal Operators*, because in ordinary input field you can input a python expression with no problems.

In modal operators it is different. Numerical input works fine, but the divide <kbd>/</kbd> and minus <kbd>-</kbd> keys function as toggles instead. <kbd>/</kbd> toggles between {input} and 1/{input}.

There is however an expression mode you can enter by pressing the <kbd>=</kbd> key first (<kbd>*</kbd> also works, which is close on numpad). You can now enter any expression, like 3/2 or 3-2 and it works.

I like to do this rather than having to apply the operator in 2 steps: 1st for the numerator and 2nd for the 1/denominator to have a resulting numerator/denominator transformation.

Note: correct order matters. If you press  <kbd>/</kbd> first, you enter into 1/{..} mode. Then if you enter expression mode, you cannot go back and get rid of the 1/{..}. You have to cancel the operator.

Comment: that's a clever one!

Comment: I am not seeing exactly what you are suggesting. You're saying to type an unrecognized symbol in order to cause a glitch that somehow ends up letting you enter 3/2?

Comment: @user14554 yes, try it. Type `*3/2` and you'll see.